# EditText elements not showing up

Tags: android

I have the following sub layout that looks like as given below, basically it is to create 25 text to take input for a `5x5` matrix but the issue is only first `EditText` is showing up rest of them are not showing up.

`Edit:` *I also tried the same thing with `RelativeLayout` but `EditText` elements didnt showed up.*

Can someone please explain why all these `EditText` are not visible?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/convolutionMatrix"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixLayoutWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginOne"
    android:background="@color/white1"
    android:padding="@dimen/marginOne" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/marginOne"
        android:text="@string/matrixTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel12"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel13"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel14"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel15"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel21"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel22"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel23"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel24"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel25"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel31"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel32"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel33"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel34"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel35"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel41"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel42"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel43"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel44"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel45"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel51"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel52"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel53"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel54"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernel55"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apply Kernel Mask" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If using  a RelativeLayout, you should be using `layout_toTLeftOf`, `layout_below` etc. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: for the `RelativeLayout` or for all individual elements inside the layout?
I dont mind using `LinearLayout` but `EditText` elements are still not appearing with it.

Comment: it's a relativelayout, they are all on top of each other. But you would already know that if you had opened hierarchyviewer, or even simply opened the graphical ui editor.

Comment: I dont mind using `LinearLayout` but `EditText` elements are still not appearing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relative layout but like the comments suggest switch to the graph ui editor and move from being on top of one another. Simple mistake we all made at the beginning.

Comment: I dont mind using `LinearLayout` but `EditText` elements are still not appearing with it.

Comment: THen use the linearLayout..  Just make sure that they arent being stacked upon another.